# multiple button presses result in single action in ios cocoa

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, timer

The title says multiple button presses, but actually I'm looking to stack multiple events.  I have a chat application that can receive many chat messages at once.  In my messageReceived function, I would like to scroll to the bottom of the most recent chats.  The problem I'm having is that sometimes many messages (50+) can come in at the same time.  I've determined that scrolling to the bottom is a huge performance bottle neck if performed 50 times, but works great if only performed after messages are received.

I'd like scroll to the bottom after a delay, say 0.1 seconds, in my messageReceived function.  But I'd like all new chat messages that occur within this 0.1 seconds to "stack", and only issue a single scroll to bottom request.

I think that a system of setting and canceling timers would work for this, however I can't get it right.  Is there a better way to make this happen! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are setting your delayed "scroll to the bottom" request with something like

```
[[self myObject] performSelector:@selector(scrollToBottom:) 
                      withObject:nil 
                      afterDelay:0.1];
```

then you can use a cancel command like

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:[self myObject]
                                        selector:@selector(scrollToBottom:)
                                      object:nil];
```

then the only time your `scrollToBottom:` gets called is when it doesn't get cancelled (so, the last time in the bunch). Now you don't need a timer.

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact solution, but something which could guide to right direction. You can set a flag in your .h file and use that to determine if the method has been already called.

In `init` method set flag as,

```
self.didCallScrollToBottomMethod = FALSE;
```

In your `scrollToBottomMethod`, check the condition as,

```
if (!self.didCallScrollToBottomMethod) {
   self.didCallScrollToBottomMethod = TRUE;
   //set the timer here to scroll after 0.1 seconds
}
```

In the timer method once the scrolling is completed, set the flag as,

```
self.didCallScrollToBottomMethod = FALSE;
```